# Improving Chrome performance on OSX

Tags: google-chrome, performance, safari

There are a number of sites that do not display properly on Safari and I need to switch to Chrome. Although when the content of the sites requires flash player, Chrome will consume a significant amount of CPU. Running more than 3 windows, will cause my MBP to overheat, start the fans, and reduce battery life way more than Safari.

> What I am looking for is suggestions on ways to improve performance of
>   Chrome running flash. I know Safari is optimised for OSX, but any improvement is welcome.

Following I have a demo to display the issue. I am running same youtube video on Safari 6 and Chrome 21,both updated,at the same time. Both browsers have been reseted and have no extensions. This is run on MBP 13" 2012 with 2.9 i7 running OSX 10.8.1.

[image]

p.s If any additional details can help please let me know.

Comment: I'm curious, what are the sites that don't display properly in Safari?

Comment: Google needs to get their act together and release a 64-bit version of Chrome for Mac. I wonder if the 32-bit version of Flash doesn't support hardware-accelerated H.264 playback or something.

Comment: Spiff it happens on few places but cant recall any specific case. Although a different example that Safari doesnt work is here: http://www.free-tv-video-online.me/player/sockshare.php?id=B9176F15B7C8B4DB . When I click on close ad and watch, nothing happens. On chrome it works.